# CSRF middleware doesn't get activated

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

## Here's what I have

Cakephp 3.7.2; in my `routes.php`:

```
<?php

use Cake\Core\Plugin;
use Cake\Routing\RouteBuilder;
use Cake\Routing\Router;
use Cake\Routing\Route\DashedRoute;
use Cake\Http\Middleware\CsrfProtectionMiddleware;

Router::defaultRouteClass(DashedRoute::class);

Router::scope('/', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
    $routes->registerMiddleware('csrf', new CsrfProtectionMiddleware());
    $routes->applyMiddleware('csrf');
    $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home']);
    $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
});
/*
Router::scope('/api', function ($routes) {
  // connect routes with *no* CSRF protection as that middleware is not active
  // for this routing scope.
});
*/
Router::prefix('api', function ($routes) {
    $routes->prefix('users', function ($routes) {
        $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
    });
});
```

## What I'm doing

Make a POST request to `/api/users` using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/). The request goes through and I see the correct response. I want to make sure I have the protection enabled for the rest of the site, so I'm expecting one of those *Missing CSRF token cookie* errors though. Once confirmed, I will uncomment the API route exception.

## What I've tried

- Follow [controllers/middleware.html#csrf-middleware](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/middleware.html#csrf-middleware) and put the `registerMiddleware()` call into `src/Application.php`
- Put some gibberish into the `applyMiddleware()` call. It complains about not being able to find that middleware, which confirms the function does get called
- Put `$this->loadComponent('Csrf');` into `AppController.php`. It works and I do get the *Missing CSRF token cookie*. It does not show me *the warning about conflicting components* like [this page](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/middleware.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-middleware) says it should

I'm under impression the middleware was not enabled properly, but it's not obvious to me what exactly is wrong. Please assist

Comment: I will be able to accept the answer and close the question in two days. I decided to keep it here for googlers. This was not obvious to me, may be not obvious to someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was actually the right setup.

I didn't realise the lower `Router::prefix` call with no middleware would negate the above `Router::scope` call (i.e. act as an exception), but it did.